# How to go up in a python loop with for

Tags: python

In other languages

```
for（i=0; i<10; i++){
    if(...){
        i = 4;
    }
}
```

the loop will go up,
but in python,it doesn't work

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    if ...:
        i = 4
```

So can I go up in a loop with 'for'?

Comment: @mshsayem: Seems like a typo IMO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python does not permit you to modify your looping variable inline. If you wish to do this you should do the following

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
   if i == 3:
       i = 7
   print(i)
   i += 1
```

This should have the effect you desire.

You can also do the following:

```
for i in range(10):
   if 2 < i < 7:
       continue
   print(i)
```

Both have the same effect.

Comment: I think I should use while instead of for in my case ,Thank you all

Answer (score 8):

One  possibility is that you want to skip items. Everything to do with looping over an index is ugly but here's a way to do that with a while loop.

```
i = 1
while i < 11:
    if predicate(i):
        i = 4
    i += 1
```

---

It's better to loop over items of the list that you want to work with directly and just skip the items that you don't want to deal with.

```
for item in some_list_of_items:
    if not predicate(item):
        continue
    do_something_with_item(item)
```

Or use a generator expression to filter the items

```
for item in (item for item in some_list_of_items if predicate(item)):
    do_something_with_item(item)
```

---

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that `range(1, 11)` returns a list and `for...in` iterates over the list elements hence changing `i` to something else doesn't work as expected. Using a `while` loop should solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Mind you that is just a bad idea. Changing iteration variable inside a for loop? In my eyes thats equivalent to a goto statement.

Why don't you just ask what you want to accomplish?

- Do you want to filter collection? Use continue statement.
- Or do you want to repeat some things more times? Create a repeat loop inside.
- Do you want iteration in different order? Well prepare the order beforehand.

The while loop solutions that others posted are correct translations, but that is not a very good idea either.

Answer (score 1):

For this case, you may want to use *while loop* instead of *for loop* in Python.
For example:

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    if ...:
        i = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Just some food for thought.

The for loop loops over an iterable.  Create your own iterable that you can move forward yourself.

```
iterator = iter(range(11))
for i in iterator:
    print 'for i = ', i
    try:
        print 'next()', iterator.next()
    except StopIteration:
        continue

>>> foo()
for i =  0
next() 1
for i =  2
next() 3
for i =  4
next() 5
for i =  6
next() 7
for i =  8
next() 9
for i =  10
next()
>>>
```

xrange() is an iterating version of range()
iterable = xrange(11) would behave as an iterator.

itertools provides nice functions like dropwhile http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile

This can proceed your iterator for you.

```
from itertools import dropwhile
iterator = iter(range(11))
for i in iterator:
    if i == 3:
        i = dropwhile(lambda x: x<8, iterator).next()
    print 'i = ', i

>>> foo()
i =  0
i =  1
i =  2
i =  8
i =  9
i =  10
>>>
```

dropwhile could be called outside your loop to create the iterator over your iteratator.
Then you can simply call next() on it. Since the for loop and the dropwhile are both calling next() on the same iterator you have some control over it.

You could also implement your own iterator that uses send() to allow you to manipulate the iterator.

http://onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2006/10/26/python-25.html?page=2