# Trying to skip over several lines but the skipped lines are still being worked on

Tags: python

My program takes an input file, reads the file using whitespace as the delimiter and puts the data into an array, then I want to iterate over each line and if certain strings are found write that info to another file.

When a specific string is found, I want to skip over several lines, meaning that these lines are NOT iterated over.  I thought that if I increased the 'line' variable (i) that would do it, but despite the fact that i is increased by 50, those 50 lines are still being worked on, which is not what I want.

Hopefully I have explained this problem well.  Thank you in advance for your feedback.

```py
def create_outfile(infile):

    gto_found = 0
    outfile = "output.txt" # Output file
    outfile = open(outfile,'w') # Open output file for writing
    for i in range(len(infile)): # iterate over each line
        if len(infile[i]) == 6: 
            if (infile[i][4][1:-1]) == "GTO" and gto_found == 0: # now skip
                print (i)
                print (infile[i])
                debugPause = input("\nPausing to debug...\n")
                i = i + 50 # Skip over the GTO section
                gto_found = 1
                print (i)
                debugPause = input("\nPausing to debug...\n")
                print (infile[i])

        for j in range(len(infile[i])): # iterate over each element

            # Command section
            if (infile[i][j])[:5] == "@ACS_": 
                # Do some work
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to go up in a python loop with for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290399/how-to-go-up-in-a-python-loop-with-for)

Comment: You should use `continue` keyword. You can do exactly what you want whit it. If your `if` statement is `True` and you don't want to run the lines inside the `if`, you can get the next item of your list with `continue` (New item of your for loop). See more details: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, python does not allow a for loop to jump up like that. The variable i cannot be edited inside the loop. This is same as this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290399/how-to-go-up-in-a-python-loop-with-for), so check it out. This other topic shows some work around that you could use.